# How can you create a new storage container on a storage account using CloudShell?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I've googled this for hours and found little code snippets in bash and powershell but the ones that don't error completely end up giving me a 403. Here's my script this far.

```
$resourceGroupName = "MyResourceGroup"
$storageAccountName = "MyStorageAcc"
$containerName = "mynewcontainer"
$storageAccKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName)[0].value
$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccKey

New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Permission Container -Context $storagecontext
```

I originally didn't get the storage account key, but after that gave me a 403 I started looking into potential reasons for the error and many suggested getting the storage account key. However this still doesn't work. What am I missing?

***Update***

I found this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9396, which suggests it's an issue with the ip address you're connecting from. However, I've added my ip address and still get the same issue.

***Update 2***

I couldn't find a sufficient way to do this through a script so decided to do it as part of the initial creation using the ARM template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your user account login the Azure powershell(if using [cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart-powershell), the account is which you login the portal) has the correct RBAC role e.g. `Storage Account Contributor` at your storage account/group/subscription, if not, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) to add it.

Besides, you mixed the old `AzureRM` command `New-AzureStorageContainer` with the new `Az` command `Get-AzStorageAccountKey`, `New-AzStorageContext`, it may cause you to use a wrong context, change the last line as below.

```
New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Permission Container -Context $storagecontext
```

Comment: Adding the user with the correct role worked